# Command block team selector

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command for a hide and seek map but I'm having this problem. The following is the command I use:

```
/effect @a[team=S] minecraft:slowness 20 10
```

The selector @a[team=S] doesn't work. It says:

```
Selector '@a[team=S]' found nothing
```

This should work because I made sure someone was on that team (me) and the team did exist. Though no matter what command I use it still comes up with the same result. The map won't really work without it.

Comment: Most likely there is nobody on the team `S`. Make sure that no commands are removing you from that team. You can only be on one team at once, so anything that makes you join another team will also make you leave that team.

Comment: make sure there are commas around the team name (i.e. `[team="S"]`

Comment: @FungusKing that's not required

Answer (score 1):

If you used the actual team name "S" as in

```
/scoreboard teams add S
```

and put players on that team, it should work fine. Try using

```
/scoreboard teams add seeker
```

and use that team instead. Additionally, try using a lowercase "s".